# Extracting data from URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to extract data from a URL using htaccess. For example, if the user access www.foo.com/12345 I want to fetch the 12345 and send user to goto?q=12345

This is what I came up with and it sort of works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^(.*)/  goto.php?q=$1
```

Two issues with the code above:

1) I lose access to any subfolder (i.e. css/ and img/)

2) If the user does not enter the a trailing slash he will get a 404

Any thoughts anyone? I've spent numerous hours and I can't figure out a better way to a fix to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ goto.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

You should use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Wow buddy! It works! That is just crazy you solved my problem in 2 minutes. THANK YOU!